# Can I collect network traffic for my app using Perfetto?

Tags: android, performance, perfetto

I'd like to save various traces, or metrics.
The reason for this is to compare performance per each versions of my application.

I want to use [Perfetto](https://perfetto.dev/docs/quickstart/android-tracing) command line tool to collect metrics and convert them into json format and upload to my DB.

**I can find cpu,mem and power metrics on Perfetto, but I cannot find network metric.**

FYI, In case of Android studio.
As shown in the following picture, I can capture network metric from my application.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is answered from here:
https://github.com/google/perfetto/issues/156

> There is no network information in traces yet. Android studio likely
> takes that from something != trace (by polling at some /proc counter
> perhaps).
>
> Nothing planned too soon on this front, so closing this.